# Empty body Api rest express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I'm trying to make an API using express in nodejs.

This api should get a request with a photo and post that photo to firebase storage.

The main problem is that for some reason the body of the requests I send are empty.

This is the code for the server:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan  = require("morgan")
const cors    = require('cors')

const app = express();

// Settings

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.set('json spaces', 4)

// middleware

app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3001"}))

// routes

app.use(require("./routes/index"))

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("Server using port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Routes

```
const { Router } = require('express')

const router  = Router()

router.post('/postImage', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const image = req.body

        console.log(image)  // Here I only get an epty object "{}"

        return res.status(200).json(image)
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).json({error})
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Client side

```
    const postImage = async (image) => {
        console.log(image)  // Here I get the image data

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/postImage", {
            method: "POST",
            body: {message: "image"}
        })

        const data = await response.json()
    }
```

I've tried using body-parser but it seems to be deprecated

Comment: Don't you think you need to have APi that will upload the file, when you do 
`console.log(image)  // Here I get the image data`, what is the  message you see. Is that a file path?

Comment: What I see is a File object (path, name, preview, size...)

Comment: I think you should use bodyparser in your app

Comment: Then you should check express to support file upload examples

Comment: You must decide whether the image shall be the entire body of your request or whether the image shall be encoded in the body, as is the case with an HTML "Upload file" button. In the latter case, you need a body-parser middleware.
Your decision will probably depend on how the Firebase API expects the image data.

Answer (score 1):

you have to send an image from the front end in formData.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('myFile', 'Image Upload');
```

In back end use multer to upload file to server.
first install multer by : npm i multer

```
const multer = require("multer");
//Configuration for Multer
const upload = multer({ dest: "public/files" });
app.post("/api/uploadFile", upload.single("myFile"), (req, res) => {
// Stuff to be added later
console.log(req.file);
});
```

[Here is a proper Guide to upload file using multer express js](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/uploading-files-using-multer-nodejs/)