# unexpected token in JSON at position 0 Api Rest file uploading

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, file-upload

I'm trying to make an API using express in nodejs.

This api should get a request with a photo and post that photo to firebase storage.

The main problem is that when the server recieves a petition with a File object it throws this error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\yupoj\Desktop\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
at parse (C:\Users\yupoj\Desktop\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
at C:\Users\yupoj\Desktop\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\yupoj\Desktop\api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (C:\Users\yupoj\Desktop\api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\yupoj\Desktop\api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

This is the code for the server:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan  = require("morgan")
const cors    = require('cors')

const app = express();

// Settings

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000)
app.set('json spaces', 4)

// middleware

app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use(express.json({limit: "1000mb"}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000"}))

// routes

app.use(require("./routes/index"))

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("Server using port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Routes

```
const { Router } = require('express')

const router  = Router()

router.post('/postImage', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("HELLO") // Code never reach here
        
        // TODO 

        return res.status(200).json({messae: "DONE"})
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).json({error})
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Client side

```
const postImage = async (image) => {
    console.log(image)

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/postImage", {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept':       'application/json',
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: image
    })

    console.log(await response.json())
}
```

Comment: What is `image`? The argument you pass to `postImage`. Is it really JSON?

Comment: image is a File type object

Comment: is it a valid JSON?

Comment: @JorgeSánchez — That isn't what you claim here: 'Content-Type': 'application/json',

Comment: Then what should I put instead of it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710311/empty-body-api-rest-express-node-js#comment121436390_68710311

Answer (score 0):

So on the client side, you have `console.log(image)` - assuming this doesn't print a nice JSON format, as this is an image so it'll more than likely print garbage.
You need to create a new object (example below) that will contain the image data. Then use this newly created object as the body of your post.

```
var json_data = {
   "image": image
}
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/postImage", {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept':       'application/json',
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: json_data
    })
```